# nvidia on schenker laptop (again)

Tags: drivers, nvidia

sorry for bringing up this seemingly well known issue again. Meanwhile I spent almost a week on it, including several reinstallations of ubuntu and I am lost.

I am running a laptop with nvidia GM204M [GeForce GTX 965M].
After the standard installation of ubuntu 15.10 everything looked fine.
However I found problems with the HDMI output.
After some research I found that the "standard" nvidia/nouveau driver seems to have restrictions here and I decided to install the proprietary nvidia driver via the "additional drivers" dialog. This worked seemingly fine.

But after a shutdown I experience the following:

GRUB: Ubuntu (normal startup)
-> "black screen"
Ctrl-Alt-F1 -> no reaction

Ctrl-Alt-Delete:
-> Advanced Options
4.2.0-23-generic recovery mode

-> recovery menu
failsafeX

-> running in low-graphics mode
OK

-> What would you like to do
any input ignored

Ctrl-Alt-F1 -> no reaction

Ctrl-Alt-Delete:
-> Advanced Options
4.2.0-23-generic recovery mode

network
root

-> console
startx

-> nvidia logo appears
empty X11 screen (background with mouse cursor) appears

I can open a terminal now

nvidia-detector results in "none"

nvidia-settings opens a graphical editor
showing the following (extract)
OS Linux-x86_64
driver version 352.63
Display Name: ubutux:2
Server Version 11.0
Server Vendor Version 1.17.2.(11702000)
NV Control Version 1.29
Screens 1

I can configure screen resolution etc.
So, everything looks good?
At least the proprietary driver seems to work in principle

"normal boot" mit acpi=off
-> "black screen"

And this posting at least helped me to get back to a partly working system after I got stuck with the proprietary drivers:
[How to solve black screen problem after installing nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 15.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691946/how-to-solve-black-screen-problem-after-installing-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-15-1)

I also tried to install and run the binary drivers from Nvidia - no luck.
Yes, I did a full reinstall afterwards to be "clean" again.

Any hints appreciated!

Kind regards

Harald

P.S. I had to remove some information in order to avoid the "spam blocker" . Feel free to ask if you need more details.

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM204M [GeForce GTX 965M]
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000013D9sv00001558sd00007702bc03sc00i00
driver   : nvidia-352-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-352 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== cpu-microcode.py ==
driver   : intel-microcode - distro non-free

harald@sky:~/ubutux$ vi post
harald@sky:~/ubutux$ cat ubuntu-drivers-devices.log 
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM204M [GeForce GTX 965M]
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000013D9sv00001558sd00007702bc03sc00i00
driver   : nvidia-352-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-352 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== cpu-microcode.py ==
driver   : intel-microcode - distro non-free

### lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a102 (rev 31)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)

00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)

00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev f1)

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f1)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 965M] (rev a1)

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)

3b:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device e0a1 (rev 10)

3c:00.0 SD Host controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5250 (rev 01)

3d:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)

### dpkg

ii  nvidia-352                                    352.63-0ubuntu0.15.10.1                    amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 352.63

ii  nvidia-common                                 1:0.4.11
                       amd64        transitional package for ubuntu-drivers-common

ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-352                         352.63-0ubuntu0.15.10.1                    amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD

ii  nvidia-prime                                  0.8.1                                      amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime

ii  nvidia-settings                               352.21-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
harald@sky:~/ubutux$

Comment: system information added:

Comment: I attempted to follow the advice given here http://askubuntu.com/a/720540/492860 but couldn't find any PRIME tab in the nvidia-settings dialog.

Answer (score 0):

partly solved:
I reinstalled ubuntu 15.10 from scratch as before but didn't encrypt the SSD (in contrast to my former installation)

Then I installed the proprietary nvidia driver via

System Settings -> Software + Updates -> Additional Drivers 352.63 nvidia-352-upgrades and deactivated the "unknown device" (again as before)

after a reboot everything (seems to) work fine