# Ubuntu 15.10 gets stuck during install (black screen and 6700HQ bug soft lockup cpu#4 stuck for 22s)

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, atheros

I have the following notebook

- SCHENKER H706 High-Performance Notebook
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970M 3072MB GDDR5
- Intel Core i7-6700HQ | 4 Kerne | 8 Threads | 2,60 - 3,50GHz | 6MB 45W
- 16GB (2x8192) SO-DIMM DDR4 RAM 2400MHz HyperX Impact
- 256GB m.2 SSD Samsung 950 Pro NVMe (MZ-V5P256BW) - angebunden via PCI-Express x4
- 500GB SATA-III SSD Samsung 850 EVO Series (MZ-75E500B)
- Qualcomm Atheros Killer Wireless-AC 1535 (inkl. Bluetooth)
- Microsoft Windows 10 Home 64 Bit english

My goal is to create a dual boot system with Ubuntu 15.10 and windows 10.

I followed this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and other web articles. I tried to run the live version from a USB stick and also to install it to HD.

I also tried to do the same thing with Lubuntu 15.10 and Fedora 23. Every time the starting console log is roughly the same (this is from Ubuntu, after 10 minutes waiting)

[image: Console log]

I think the problem could be the WIFI card. [Here](http://www.killernetworking.com/support/knowledge-base/17-linux) it's explained that it's necessary to update the firmware, but since I cannot log into Ubuntu I don't know how I can do it.

By the way I managed to get it working launching Fedora in light mode. In the network panel there wasn't any reference to my WIFI card. Maybe it worked because it skipped the card configuration.

Is there any way to install Ubuntu 15.10 from a USB stick?

**EDIT:**

I tried Ubuntu 16.04 and two times it showed only a black screen, but once it went into the first screen, with the desktop background and tool bar at the top. Sadly there wasn't any mouse cursor so I couldn't do anything: I think it's too early to use it.

I tried also OpenSuse, and this is the log I had

[image: OpenSuse]

Once more it stops by the atheros module

Comment: Try booting with `nomodeset` - see [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2300497) of similar hardware laptop, also has instructions for the same wifi firmware.

Comment: You could try `brokenmodules=ath10k_pci` in Suse as it suggests, but missing firmware shouldn't cause the system to fail to boot, it is more likely to be CPU or GPU problem, 6700HQ is a very new processor, only a few months old. Also see [Can't get Intel HD Graphics 530 (Skylake i7 6700) to work](http://askubuntu.com/questions/698168/cant-get-intel-hd-graphics-530-skylake-i7-6700-to-work) and [Xorg on skylake graphics hangs](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248972/xorg-on-skylake-graphics-hangs).

Comment: nomodeset did the trick, thank you!. You should update your answer so I can accept it. Sadly the system was slow, especially with the proprietary Nvidia drivers. Plus the network card worked only the first time I installed its firmware. After that even the wired network didn't work. I will retry when version 16.04 will come out.

Comment: Also see [No version of Ubuntu can be installed with any Skylake 6th generation Intel processor](http://askubuntu.com/questions/691216/no-version-of-ubuntu-can-be-installed-with-any-6th-generation-intel-processor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

6700HQ is a very new Skylake CPU and not well supported yet. Try booting with kernel parameter `nomodeset`. Alternatively you might be able to get modesetting to work by installing a recent mainline kernel and booting with `i915.preliminary_hw_support=1`.

It looks like your kernel is also reporting [kernel bug #109081 - Freezes with Intel i7 6700HQ (Skylake)](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109081). It might help to boot with kernel parameter `intel_idle.max_cstate=7`. You might also benefit from installing the latest upstream kernel and any firmware updates for your laptop.

The latest [16.04 daily](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) should work better than 15.10.

Comment: How long would it take before Skylake is fully supported(i.e Which Ubuntu version would work like a charm)?