# HD Graphics 530 (i7-6700) & latest stable kernel

Tags: intel-graphics

I'm going to buy an i7-6700 skylake processor (along with an Asus Z170-A motherboard), and I intend to install Ubuntu Mate 15.10.

Should I expect troubles with the integrated Intel HD Graphics 530? Will it work out-of-the-box? 
If not, does at least the latest stable kernel (4.4) support HD Graphics 530? How to make it work?

Thanks

UPDATE (Feb 4, 2016): I finally got my Intel i7-6700 processor on an ASUS Z170-Deluxe motherboard and actually it was surprisingly easy to install Ubuntu Mate 15.10. Everything works seamlessly. No issue at all, up to now.

Comment: [Yes](http://askubuntu.com/questions/721569/ubuntu-15-10-gets-stuck-during-install-6700hq-bug-soft-lockup-cpu4-stuck-for-2), [expect](http://askubuntu.com/questions/698168/cant-get-intel-hd-graphics-530-skylake-i7-6700-to-work) [trouble](http://askubuntu.com/questions/694453/new-laptop-skylake-cannot-boot-xubuntu-even-with-boot-parameters). 6700HQ has problems..

Comment: oh... still problems? also with the kernel 4.4?  :(

Comment: The last comment [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109081) says that 4.4 is still affected. If you're willing to go to some effort it sounds like it will probably work in the end with a new kernel and some incantation of parameters, but I wouldn't expect it to work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

*Nothing works... When you switch to 'Intel HD530' there is a freeze and a reboot. **It is necessary to wait for a stable kernel.***

Details of my configuration:

- Intel 6700HQ (Intel HD530), DEXP H168
- Ubuntu 15.10
- Kernel 4.4.0.999 [19.01.2016]
- Intel_Graphic 1.2.1
- Nvidia-352 (Prime)

  ```
  $ lspci | grep VGA
  (00:02.0)   VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 191b (rev 0.6)
  ```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/515080)

Comment: It's the answer. I said that even with the latest kernel and all kinds of changes to it, the decision isn't still there.

Comment: Excuse me Edelweiss, I didn't read the question. Seems that what he is asking for. Could you add output of `uname -a`

Comment: **Edelweiss: *next time, put the answer on the first line.***  Now it looked like you were having the problem as well.  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

I have a Toshiba Satellite L55-5392 which has an Intel Skylake i7 6700.  Everything works well with 14.04 using the 4.2 kernel.  The graphics are very stable, the HDMI output works fine (both dual monitor and mirroring work).  Just for the sake of being complete, all of the other controllers (SATA, ethernet, wifi, bluetooth, USB 3.0) are Intel, and they all are working flawlessly for me on the 4.2 kernel.

In my experience, the graphics were somewhat unstable using 14.04 with the 4.4 kernel.  They may be fine on 15.10 and higher, since the 4.4 kernel is probably better supported.  For reference, I use the Cinnamon desktop environment, and can't tell you if things are more stable on Unity or other environments.