# Problem with installing Ubuntu on ASUS N552VX

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, 16.10

I have problem with installing Ubuntu. I have downloaded Ubuntu 16.10 and installed it via a USB drive. I have Windows 10, and I want to install it beside Windows. When I choose install Ubuntu it stuck in Ubuntu logo and everything stops. The only way is turn off laptop manually. Is there any solution for this?

I selected try Ubuntu and it entered in Ubuntu but my laptop fan started work fast and it doesn't stop.

Thanks.

Comment: Have switched off secure boot in the BIOS.

Comment: What's your computer's firmware? `UEFI`, or `csma`, ensure that you install Your ubuntu with the same firmware you installed your windows 10. And furthermore, switch off secure boot.

Comment: it is UEFI and my windows 10 is installed in the same framware

Comment: i dont get this ...what do you mean?

Comment: And is that the same way you are installing Ubuntu? have you done the image uefi settings?

Comment: yes i  boot it in uefi... but it stuck in ubuntu logo

Comment: yes secure boot is disabled

Comment: and sure the secure boot is off?

Comment: yes it is off in security option

Comment: "Have you switched off secure boot", window machines have a setting that might prevent install of Ubuntu. Turn that off and see if you can install. And its done in the BIOS.

Comment: it works when i select try ubuntu but my fan start working fast and it not stop until shutdown computer

Comment: yes it is disabled from boot setup in security option

Comment: How about legacy mode?

Comment: what's your PC specifications, RAM, CPU speed and number of cores?

Comment: i have core i7  6700hq cpu and nvidia gtx950 and 8 g ram

Comment: i didnt try lgacy mode because in boot setup there is no option to switch between uefi and lagacy

Comment: Try and switch legacy mode off and try reinstalling, or live booting

Comment: if i use lagacy it doesent recognize my windows?

Comment: Then your windows aint installed in UEFI mode..

Comment: no it does installed in uefi it doesnt change in lagacy either.. it stuck when i press ctrl+alt+delete it says scsi host4 pm trying activate but the host 4 child device is not activated

Comment: i managed to install ubuntu with this answer  http://askubuntu.com/questions/721569/ubuntu-15-10-gets-stuck-during-install-black-screen-and-6700hq-bug-soft-lockup but when i installed it .,i should write ni=omodeset every time my laptop boot up.and my graphic is not loaded

Comment: I did a Google search on `ubuntu asus n552vx` and found a number of hits describing the same symptoms, but no solutions. I therefore suspect a hardware incompatibility. You might try the pre-release build of [Ubuntu 17.04,](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) in the hopes that it fixes the problem, but that is a long shot. Beyond that, I suggest you [file a bug report.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) There's also a long [question and answers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) about dealing with Ubuntu freezes.

Comment: This problem encountered to me after the update of the windows 10 creators edition. Sometimes it helps to load windows and reboot to linux afterwards - but I could not prove any corellation yet. From my observations the problem seems to be related to the nvidia graphics card. Booting into the rescue mode worked for me every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved the problem:):)

1. Update the bios.
   Download the latest BIOS, I uses the BIOS 300.
   https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/VivoBook-Pro-N552VX/HelpDesk_Manual/
   https://www.asus.com/se/support/Download/3/837/0/1/BiXix0ldv4rQc6sc/45/
   To update the BIOS:

   1. Verify the Notebook PC’s exact model then download the latest
      BIOS file for your model from the ASUS website.
   2. Save a copy of the downloaded BIOS file to a flash disk drive.
   3. Connect your flash disk drive to your Notebook PC.
   4. Restart your Notebook PC then press during POST.
   5. From the BIOS menu, select Advanced > Start Easy Flash, then
      press enter
   6. Locate your downloaded BIOS file in the flash disk drive then
      press enter
   7. After the BIOS update process, select Exit > Restore Defaults to
      restore the system to its default settings.
2. Enter the bios and disable fast boot, save and exit bios
3. Install the Ubuntu 16.10
4. Set acpi_osi=! in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

   - Open a terminal
   - Open up /etc/default/grub, you'll need root privs to edit.
   - Goto the line:
   - `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"`
   - and add the parameters
   - `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_osi=!"`
   - Save.
   - `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
   - Reboot
     And now to works!!
     /XMEN01

Comment: tnx man,finally i installed ubuntu!

Comment: Dont forget to update the config using `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Look here why do you need to add `acpi_osi`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/28848/what-does-the-kernel-boot-parameter-set-acpi-osi-linux-do