# Ubuntu Installation: Attempt to mount a filesystem with type ext4 in SCSI7 (0,0,0). partition #1 at / failed.

Tags: partitioning

I'm seeking help with an issue I'm having with my Ubuntu install.

I have a new HP Zbook with an SSD. Windows 7 was installed on it without a problem.

First I tried the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option. After going through all of various steps, the install fails with this message:

"Attempt to mount a filesystem with type ext4 in SCSI7 (0,0,0). partition #1 at / failed."

Each time that this happens, I am forced to reboot because GParted and the installer are unable to detect any partition details from the drive.

I know that I'm not the first to post about this error message. I've been googling and reading about this for a couple of days now. I've tried all of the solutions that seemed to work for those other posts.

Here are some of the approaches that I've taken that have failed.

1) Be sure that the boot more is AHCI. 
It is.

2) Install the partitions before doing the install. 
The live ISO that I'm booting to is shipped with GParted 0.18.0. I tried making an ext4 partition. The operation completes and then I get an error: "Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda: Remote I/O error"
So I downloaded the live Gparted ISO which runs version 0.24.0 and booted that. With this version I was able to partition the ext4 partition and a swap partition to use for the install. Once I booted back into the install I chose the "Something Else" option and selected those partitions. I told the ext4 to mount to /. After selecting the country I get a new error: " [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/target/bin'."

I'm pretty stuck. I can provide any additional information or run any diagnostic commands upon request.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: These are the specifications for the hardware: https://www.shi.com/Products/ProductDetail.aspx?SHISystemID=ShiCommodity&ProductIdentity=30883236&contshop=1&SDIMResults=ctgy3:%27Hardware%20>%20Computers%20>%20Notebooks%20and%20Tablets%27&searches=P3D85UT%23ABA%3b&sort=BestMatch&offset=0&recsperpg=20&EventID=8a68f4a7-5afa-45a8-933f-8746b867ac16

Comment: [Check media for defects](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck). If that works, try instlal and after you get the "read only file system" error do `dmesg` and check for errors... What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? Could you try 16.04 to test whether a later kernel helps?

Comment: Thanks bain! I've tried Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and it failed. I tried Linux Mint 17.3 (this is the distribution that I would prefer to run) and it failed with the same sets of errors. I also tried Ubuntu MATE 14.04.2 LTS today and it installed with out any problems. After that I decided to attempt to install Mint again but ran into the same issues.  I'm currently trying to figure out what's different about MATE and why I don't get those errors when installing it.  The media check doesn't find any issues. I will run dmesg and share the output after my next attempt.

Comment: I will add dmesg output.

Comment: If this is a new system you may have more luck with 16.04 which has a newer kernel. If it's a skylake system then have a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/691216/no-version-of-ubuntu-can-be-installed-with-any-skylake-6th-generation-intel-proc) and linked answers.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: MikeD, can you share which version of the kernel worked?
EDIT2: Seems kernel 3.13 works. It would be nice to understand if any newer versions will work.

I don't have a solution yet, but don't have the reputation to comment (so apologies for this being an "answer"). I've fought the same issue on 2 different HP ZBook 14 G2 laptops - each with a Liteon CX1-JB512-HP PCIe SSD. What's even more interesting is that, when trying to format ext4 partitions, gparted somehow screws with the existing Windows/NTFS partitions. There's gotta be something related to this hardware. Fresh installs of Windows 7 work without any issue.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Everything you are saying is familiar. I had no problem with Windows 7. I'm not able to install Ubuntu or Linux Mint. I get the attempt to partition failed message. What's stranger is that I am able to install Ubuntu MATE on this machine without any issue. I'm not a huge fan of MATE so I'm still trying to get my Mint install to work. I just can't fathom how Ubuntu MATE installs without an issue but Ubuntu doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those who replied! It turns out that the kernel version that was shipped with the installers I was using was not compatible with the hardware. I used and older version of Mint (17.1) and that kernel worked perfectly.

Comment: Which hardware was incompatible? Is there a bug report anywhere?