# Not able to install ubuntu on msi PE 70 6QE

Tags: system-installation

I burnt a dvd from windows installation of 16.04 lts 64 bit. During boot, I disabled fastboot, secure boot and Intel speed step. I chose install ubuntu option, after about couple of minutes installation seems to hang, as progress animation stops. Any ideas? Just bought this laptop yesterday, I am totally stuck now. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does it have NVIDIA graphics?

Comment: Yes it has NVIDIA GTX960M.

Comment: OK. Boot into the GRUB menu and highlight the "Try Ubuntu" option. Press 'E' and put `nouveau.modeset=0` after the line beginning with `linux`. Press `F10` to boot. See if that fixes your issue. You should then follow this guide after installing http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics/760935#760935

Comment: Would it disable Nvidia graphics? I bought this laptop mainly for Nvidia.

Comment: It will temporarily. You have to boot with it for the installation and then once or twice after installation until you install the proprietary drivers. My answer in the linked Q&A explains what to do after you install.

Comment: That did not help, I also tried acpi=off, but result is same, stuck after few minutes

Comment: Hmm. You may have to try redowbloading and reburning the installer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I misunderstood your earlier instruction, now I put noveau.modeset=0 and acpi=off in the linux line, before quiet splash, now it did boot, now I need to try installing.

Comment: Somehow installation did complete but it boots into windows only, I had selected dual boot with windows boot manager. It said about repairing something, looks like it erased ubuntu, should I try linux only boot, would be nice to keep windows for games, docs, etc.

Comment: there's an ISO called boot-repair, available from community.ubuntu.com. Look that up.

Comment: I could do boot repair after  booting from ubuntu live cd and boot ubuntu. However, in attempt to fix  nvidia per instructions in link you mentioned above, boot is broken, can not boot ubuntu now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to very precise inputs from Zachary and some inputs from other forums, I am finally able to get Ubuntu up, still not tested much on Nvidia drivers, assuming it is okay. Following is summary of what I tried --

Problems 1> Nvidia support in Live CD 2> BIOS configuration 3>Dual boot management 4> acpi

1> Created DVD ROM ( Live CD )for 16.04 LTS from Windows ( Right click on iso, burn image )
2> BIOS parameters -- Fast boot off, Intel Speed startup off, Secure boot off ( Hold Del while booting )
3> Boot from Live CD/DVD, on the initial menu ( try boot, install ubuntu .. ) select try boot and press e ( could have been install ), changed the line containing linux , added noveau.modeset=0 acpi=off before quiet splash
4> Followed more or less something like following. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall
During installation selected ubuntu side by side windows, did not erase windows, installed ubuntu in hard disk space suggested by installer ( two partitions around 300 + 200 )
5> Ran boot repair from within ubuntu --https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
 booted with try boot ( This was possibly not necessary as I had not checked the BIOS boot order option below earlier )
6> To boot from ubuntu -- selected ubuntu first in BIOS boot order
7> Followed instructions to change Nvidia libs -- 
[Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics/760935#760935)
After this I was able to remove noveau.modeset=0
8> In BIOS select UEFI with CSM, after this I was able to remove acpi=off from boot
9> Had some problem with touch pad, it would not respond. I changed bootup numlock state to off, most likely it does not have any correlation but my touch pad is now working

Answer (score 0):

In order to get Ubuntu installed, and also working after installation, I needed to do a little song and dance with grub boot options and a package installation, while avoiding the GUI.  Much of the information contained in this post was relevant to my troubleshooting: [No version of Ubuntu can be installed with any Skylake 6th generation Intel processor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691216/no-version-of-ubuntu-can-be-installed-with-any-skylake-6th-generation-intel-proc/691245)

I did not want to complicate the driver issue with getting UEFI working, so in this example I went with using the "legacy" mode in the BIOS to boot into linux, and UEFI to boot into Windows.

I installed this version: VERSION="16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
Which includes this kernel: 4.4.0-38-generic
This allowed me to avoid having to recompile a 4.3+ kernel for proper support.

I had no issues with installing Ubuntu from a USB drive, and did not need to pass any boot options to the installer to get it to complete.
Logging into a GUI after installation however would cause the system to lockup with a CPU getting pinned at 100% due to an lspci command.

In order to get the system functional, I took these steps:

1. When presented with the lightdm login screen, I switched to a
   terminal (CTRL+ALT+[1-4])
2. After logging in, edited the /etc/default/grub boot options to be: `splash nomodeset i915.preliminary_hw_support=1`
3. Edited /etc/initramfs-tools/modules and added: `i195  nvme`
4. Updated grub configuration: `sudo update-grub`
5. Hard reset the laptop (Hold down power button).
6. Login to a terminal again, NOT the GUI.
7. Apt-get update and install the nvidia-361 package: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-361`.  This installed the
   necessary firmware drivers and built the kernel modules.
8. Edit the /etc/default/grub boot options, and reset them to default.
9. Updated grub configuration: `sudo update-grub`
10. Reboot, and enjoy!