# Will my motherboard support Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, compatibility, migration

Greetings I recently upgraded my system to a new motherboarda and a new processor, (well I guess new  everything) except my hard drives, which contain my operating system which is Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

The new motherboard is a [GIGABYTE Z170N](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5529#ov) On their website it specifies that it will support Windows operating systems, but there was no mention of Linux or Ubuntu.

Just wondering if the migration of my system will actually work with this motherboard?

Comment: From a review posted [elsewhere](http://www.amazon.com/Gigabyte-LGA1151-Mini-ITX-Motherboards-GA-Z170N-Gaming/dp/B014W2000Q) this motherboard apparently supports 16.04

Answer (score 1):

Latest Ubuntu 14.04 (14.04.4) uses kernel 4.2 which will probably run with skylake processors (intel 6th gen) but maybe need some configuration (probably nomodeset boot option and upgrade to newer kernel as discussed here [No version of Ubuntu can be installed with any Skylake 6th generation Intel processor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691216/no-version-of-ubuntu-can-be-installed-with-any-skylake-6th-generation-intel-proc)). The best way to be sure is to write an ubuntu usb live image and choose test ubuntu instead of install. So, I recommend that you try a clean ubuntu 16.04 install which has kernel 4.4 (you can also upgrade to kernel 4.5 or 4.6 series as they supposed to have more skylake fixes and improvements, but they may cause instability to your system).

Keep in mind that if you use intel graphics there are not any proprietary skylake drivers for linux yet and opensource drivers are at an early stage yet (maybe when 16.04.1 is released there will be better support). Some benchmarks for ubuntu 15.10 (ubuntu 16.04 may be a bit better) are here: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel-skylake-windows&num=2. So, you should probably consider installing newest kernel (4.6 series) and adding this ppa https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers?field.series_filter=xenial (there's a risk to make your system unstable).

Comment: I will not be using the integrated graphics chip but an ASUS GeForce GTX 970 Strix. Hopefully there is some support for that?

Comment: yeah gtx 970 is supported at both 14.04 and 16.04 , however there have been reported some problems with nvidia drivers at 16.04 but if you have any you most likely find a solution at askubuntu.

Comment: do you think migrating an already installed 14.04 will work out ok with this motherboard?

Comment: It supposed to, make sure you have updated the system, uninstall any proprietary drivers and if you want to be sure install kernel 4.5 for better drivers support (usually problems with new hardware are ethernet, wifi, sound)