# Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS doesn't shut down in a MSI PX60 6QE laptop

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, shutdown

I have dual boot `Windows 10` and `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS` in two partitions in a `ssd`.

Everything works fine, GRUB appears and I can decide which OS to boot.

However, I have an error when shut downing Ubuntu. It proceeds to shut down the laptop, but it freezes in the shutdown screen. And finally being forced to shut it down the hard way.

I have tried some options like the `nomodeset` or the `acpi force` in the `/etc/default/grub` file. Nevertheless it doesn't shut down.

What more can I try to solve it?

**Edit:**

I have this output. It freezes in `# Will now halt`, but it doesn't.

[image: Sys log]

*Sorry for bad quality.*

Comment: Consult the system logs and post any errors here. Also, how long did you let your computer sit before it shut down?

Comment: @patrickyi I have added a picture, is this what you asked? Also, the computer doesn't shut down, I must do it by force (by presssing shutdown button).

Comment: looks like linux doesn't know about the ACPI magic required for your laptop , at least not in the kernel you are running. Maybe try a newer kernel to see if that helps.

Comment: @Amias I have `4.4.0-38-generic` kernel version. I think this problem has a faster solution, but if no solution is received, I will try what you suggest.

Comment: that laptop has a very new chipset that around a year old so looks to be very much in the latest kernels only territory. It also seems to have a some extra gaming specific power management that might well not be supported by linux yet.

Answer (score 0):

Add the command acpi=off to your grub boot. That may or may not work.

As an FYI, this is an acpi error-
the "Will now halt", and then the corresponding freeze, means that your computer has completely shut off the CPU and other components. You can safely shut the power down- holding the power button shouldn't result in power loss.

TL;DR- It's perfectly fine to shut down the computer by holding the power button

Also, consider upgrading to 16.04.

Comment: I changed line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"` and then `update-grub`. But the same happens, it doesn't shut down. Although it is nice to shut down the laptop by holding the power button, I'd like not to do it. Also I couldn't install 16.04 because Skylake compatibility problems, so I should maintain in 14.04, at least for now.

Comment: Do you have the sleep state issue under 16.04? 16.04 has better support for Skylake than 14.04. I managed to fix it on a laptop I have running an i5-6200u, and I get to C7.

Comment: No I havn't it. Yes I know, but it was impossible to install it, and I only could install `14.04.5` (enough for me).

Comment: See this thread for your device: http://askubuntu.com/questions/772977/not-able-to-install-ubuntu-on-msi-pe-70-6qe

Comment: It also freezed during the installation. I also tried many `bios options` and `kernel parameters`, but nothing worked. In the end I could manage to install `14.04.5`, helped by this community [in this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/829478/installing-ubuntu-with-dual-boot-windows-10-crashes-in-msi-px60-6qe-laptop).

Comment: Well, expect compatibility and issues when using an older version of Ubuntu. I would also upgrade your kernel to 4.7, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same incomplete shutdown:

```
Will now halt
reboot: System halted
```

After trying all sorts of suggestions, I have commented out the following line in `/etc/default/grub`, run `update-grub` and everything returned back to normality:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=off noapic nolapic nomodeset"
```

I have no idea how and why it has surfaced there in the first place though.