# Ubuntu 16.04 Skylake overheating

Tags: 16.04, power-management, overheating, powertop, intel-cpu

I recently bought a laptop boarding a skylake i7-6700hq processor, and I managed to install Ubuntu 16.04, however, I noticed that the laptop was overheating resulting to a very short battery life while on Ubuntu (1,5 hour while it lasts 6 hours on Windows).

So I ran `powertop` , and I noticed that my processor never goes below the PC2 state, and thus even on idle. I also tried running `powertop –auto-tune` and even if there is a slight improvement, the processor never goes below PC3.

I've also tried upgrading the kernel, moving from the 4.4 ubuntu to 4.7, but it had no effect.

To be frank I'm completely clueless against that issue, that's why I'm coming to you.
I'm also attaching `powertop` output.

Thanks for your help !

```
____________________________________________________________________
            P o w e r T O P

____________________________________________________________________
 *  *  *   System Information   *  *  *

PowerTOP Version;v2.8 ran at Tue Sep 27 18:33:11 2016

Kernel Version;Linux version 4.8.0-040800rc7-generic
System Name;Notebook                        P640RENot Applicable                  
CPU Information;8 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
OS Information;Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Target: 1 units/s;System:  196.8 wakeup/s;CPU:  3.0% usage;GPU: 0.9 ops/s;GFX: 7.7 wakeups/s;VFS: 0 ops/s;

____________________________________________________________________
 *  *  *   Top 10 Power Consumers   *  *  *

Usage;Events/s;Category;Description
100,0%;;Device;Codec audio hwC0D0 : Realtek
  1,0%; 48,7;Process;nm-applet 
  0,4%; 26,4;Process;/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon 
  0,0%; 20,8;Timer;tick_sched_timer
  0,2%; 14,9;Process;compiz 
  0,0%; 16,4;Process;upstart-dbus-bridge --daemon --system --user --bus-name system 
  0,0%; 14,1;Process;[rcu_sched]
  0,0%; 10,7;Process;[irq/132-iwlwifi]
  0,0%;  6,8;kWork;ieee80211_iface_work
  0,1%;  4,2;Process;/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch 

____________________________________________________________________
 *  *  *   Processor Idle State Report   *  *  *

Package;0
C2 (pc2); 95,1%
C3 (pc3);  0,0%
C6 (pc6);  0,0%
C7 (pc7);  0,0%
C8 (pc8);  0,0%
C9 (pc9);  0,0%
C10 (pc10);  0,0%
;
;
;

;Core 0
C3 (cc3);  0,0%
C6 (cc6);  0,6%
C7 (cc7); 96,5%
;Core 1
C3 (cc3);  0,0%
C6 (cc6);  0,1%
C7 (cc7); 99,2%
;Core 2
C3 (cc3);  0,0%
C6 (cc6);  5,2%
C7 (cc7); 93,4%
;Core 3
C3 (cc3);  0,0%
C6 (cc6);  0,2%
C7 (cc7); 98,5%

CPU;0;CPU;4
C0 actif;  0,3%;  0,2%;
POLL;  0,0%;   0,0 ms;  0,0%;   0,0 ms
C1E-SKL;  0,3%;   1,3 ms;  0,2%;   0,1 ms
;
C3-SKL;  0,0%;   0,4 ms;  0,0%;   0,1 ms
C6-SKL;  0,1%;  13,4 ms;  1,4%;  10,1 ms
C7s-SKL;  0,0%;   0,0 ms;  0,0%;   0,0 ms
C8-SKL;  0,5%;   4,9 ms; 14,7%;  73,5 ms
C9-SKL;  0,0%;   0,0 ms;  0,0%;   0,0 ms
C10-SKL; 96,3%; 137,6 ms; 83,5%; 222,7 ms
CPU;1;CPU;5
C0 actif;  0,2%;  0,2%;
POLL;  0,0%;   0,0 ms;  0,0%;   0,0 ms
C1E-SKL;  0,1%;   0,5 ms;  0,3%;   0,3 ms
;
C3-SKL;  0,0%;   0,0 ms;  0,0%;   0,0 ms
C6-SKL;  0,0%;   0,4 ms;  0,1%;   0,9 ms
C7s-SKL;  0,0%;   0,0 ms;  0,0%;   0,2 ms
C8-SKL;  1,4%;   7,0 ms;  5,6%;  11,4 ms
C9-SKL;  0,0%;   0,0 ms;  0,0%;   0,0 ms
C10-SKL; 98,2%;  66,6 ms; 93,5%; 126,4 ms
CPU;2;CPU;6
C0 actif;  0,2%;  1,0%;
POLL;  0,0%;   0,0 ms;  0,0%;   0,0 ms
C1E-SKL;  0,0%;   0,4 ms;  0,1%;   0,1 ms
;
C3-SKL;  0,0%;   0,2 ms;  0,0%;   0,0 ms
C6-SKL;  0,3%;   0,7 ms;  5,0%;  15,5 ms
C7s-SKL;  0,0%;   0,0 ms;  0,0%;   0,0 ms
C8-SKL;  3,0%;   5,1 ms;  0,4%;   2,8 ms
C9-SKL;  0,0%;   0,0 ms;  0,0%;   0,0 ms
C10-SKL; 95,9%;  54,9 ms; 93,5%; 199,0 ms
CPU;3;CPU;7
C0 actif;  0,3%;  0,3%;
POLL;  0,0%;   0,0 ms;  0,0%;   0,0 ms
C1E-SKL;  0,1%;   0,6 ms;  0,0%;   0,2 ms
;
C3-SKL;  0,0%;   0,3 ms;  0,0%;   0,3 ms
C6-SKL;  0,0%;   0,4 ms;  0,2%;   0,9 ms
C7s-SKL;  0,0%;   0,1 ms;  0,0%;   0,0 ms
C8-SKL;  0,8%;   2,9 ms; 10,8%;   4,1 ms
C9-SKL;  0,0%;   0,0 ms;  0,0%;   0,0 ms
C10-SKL; 98,6%; 163,0 ms; 87,9%; 170,8 ms
;;;;
;;;;
;;;;
;;;;
;;;;
;;;;
;;;;
;;;;
;;;;
;;;;
;;;;
;;;;

____________________________________________________________________
 *  *  *   Processor Frequency Report   *  *  *

Package;0
Idle; 100,0% 
;
;
;

;Core 0
Idle; 100,0% 
;Core 1
Idle; 100,0% 
;Core 2
Idle; 100,0% 
;Core 3
Idle; 100,0% 

CPU 0;CPU 4
Réel;2,0 GHz;2,0 GHz
Idle; 100,0% ; 100,0% 
CPU 1;CPU 5
Réel;1,9 GHz;1,8 GHz
Idle; 100,0% ; 100,0% 
CPU 2;CPU 6
Réel;  1105 MHz;3,0 GHz
Idle; 100,0% ; 100,0% 
CPU 3;CPU 7
Réel;1,7 GHz;1,8 GHz
Idle; 100,0% ; 100,0% 
;;
;;
;;
;;

____________________________________________________________________
 *  *  *   Overview of Software Power Consumers   *  *  *

Usage;Wakeups/s;GPU ops/s;Disk IO/s;GFX Wakeups/s;Category;Description
  9,9 ms/s; 48,7;;;;Process;nm-applet 
  4,5 ms/s; 26,4;;;;Process;/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon 
298,3 us/s; 20,8;;;;Timer;tick_sched_timer
  2,2 ms/s; 13,9;  0,9;;  3,0;Process;compiz 
316,3 us/s; 16,4;;;;Process;upstart-dbus-bridge --daemon --system --user --bus-name system 
156,6 us/s; 14,1;;;;Process;[rcu_sched]
397,0 us/s; 10,7;;;;Process;[irq/132-iwlwifi]
 41,3 us/s;  6,8;;;;kWork;ieee80211_iface_work
  1,1 ms/s;  4,2;;;  3,2;Process;/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch 
  1,7 ms/s;  3,9;;;  0,7;Process;nautilus -n 
  2,2 ms/s;  3,5;;;;Process;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unity/unity-panel-service 
  5,4 us/s;  2,2;;;;Timer;intel_uncore_fw_release_timer
 21,8 us/s;  1,9;;;;Process;[i915/signal:0]
337,2 us/s;  1,5;;;  0,8;Process;/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server 
 96,4 us/s;  1,6;;;;kWork;cache_reap
193,7 us/s;  1,6;;;;Process;/lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd 
  3,3 ms/s;;;;;Process;/usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation 
 68,8 us/s;  1,2;;;;Process;upstart-dbus-bridge --daemon --session --user --bus-name session 
623,1 us/s;  0,9;;;;Process;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service 
 15,8 us/s;  1,0;;;;kWork;gen6_pm_rps_work
  8,3 us/s;  1,0;;;;kWork;pci_pme_list_scan
  7,6 us/s;  1,0;;;;Interrupt;[6] tasklet(softirq)
  8,7 us/s;  0,9;;;;kWork;intel_unpin_work_fn
  0,0 us/s;  0,9;;;;kWork;intel_mmio_flip_work_func
 51,8 us/s;  0,8;;;;Process;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-application/indicator-application-service 
594,1 us/s;  0,6;;;;Process;/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant 
  3,2 us/s;  0,7;;;;Timer;sched_rt_period_timer
  4,7 us/s;  0,5;;;;kWork;iwl_pcie_rx_allocator_work
 20,9 us/s;  0,5;;;;Process;gpg-agent --homedir /home/t/.gnupg --use-standard-socket --daemon 
  7,9 us/s;  0,5;;;;kWork;vmstat_shepherd
  1,7 us/s;  0,5;;;;kWork;mei_timer
 24,4 us/s;  0,4;;;;Process;gpg-agent
  0,8 ms/s; 0,10;;;;Interrupt;[7] sched(softirq)
  0,6 us/s;  0,4;;;;kWork;cfq_kick_queue
 21,4 us/s; 0,30;;;;kWork;i915_gem_idle_work_handler
 13,4 us/s; 0,30;;;;Process;/usr/lib/rtkit/rtkit-daemon 
 96,6 us/s; 0,25;;;;Process;/usr/sbin/thermald --no-daemon --dbus-enable 
 62,7 us/s; 0,25;;;;kWork;i915_hangcheck_elapsed
 26,8 us/s; 0,25;;;;Process;pool
 13,7 us/s; 0,25;;;;Process;/usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service 
 13,0 us/s; 0,25;;;;Process;zeitgeist-datahub 
 12,5 us/s; 0,25;;;;Process;/usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon 
  1,9 us/s; 0,25;;;;Process;[watchdog/4]
  1,8 us/s; 0,25;;;;Process;[watchdog/0]
  1,8 us/s; 0,25;;;;Process;[watchdog/7]
  1,7 us/s; 0,25;;;;Process;[watchdog/5]
  1,6 us/s; 0,25;;;;Process;[watchdog/6]
  1,6 us/s; 0,25;;;;Process;[watchdog/3]
  1,5 us/s; 0,25;;;;Process;[watchdog/2]
  1,5 us/s; 0,25;;;;Process;[watchdog/1]
  0,4 us/s; 0,25;;;;kWork;blk_delay_work
 81,0 us/s; 0,20;;;;Interrupt;[130] i915
 13,2 us/s; 0,20;;;;Process;update-notifier 
  5,9 us/s; 0,15;;;;kWork;wb_workfn
  4,3 us/s; 0,15;;;;Process;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fwupd/fwupd 
 83,0 us/s; 0,10;;;;Process;/usr/sbin/irqbalance --pid=/var/run/irqbalance.pid 
 42,3 us/s; 0,10;;;;Process;/usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon 
 32,9 us/s; 0,10;;;;Interrupt;[4] block(softirq)
 16,7 us/s; 0,10;;;;Process;[jbd2/sda5-8]
  3,4 us/s; 0,10;;;;Process;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/bamf/bamfdaemon 
  2,4 us/s; 0,10;;;;kWork;__cfg80211_sched_scan_results
128,5 us/s; 0,05;;;;Timer;hrtimer_wakeup
  1,7 us/s; 0,10;;;;Process;/usr/lib/snapd/snapd 
  0,2 us/s; 0,10;;;;kWork;blk_timeout_work
227,9 us/s;;;;;Process;dbus-daemon --fork --session --address=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-n69HY0fcq8 
148,0 us/s;;;;;Interrupt;[1] timer(softirq)
  1,7 us/s; 0,05;;;;Process;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service 
  0,5 us/s; 0,05;;;;kWork;push_to_pool
  0,2 us/s; 0,05;;;;kWork;neigh_periodic_work
  0,2 us/s; 0,05;;;;kWork;cgroup_pidlist_destroy_work_fn
105,9 us/s;;;;;Interrupt;[9] RCU(softirq)
104,8 us/s;;;;;Process;[kworker/u16:0]
 97,8 us/s;;;;;Timer;process_timeout
 64,3 us/s;;;;;Process;/sbin/init splash 
 54,3 us/s;;;;;Timer;delayed_work_timer_fn
 48,8 us/s;;;;;Process;[kworker/5:1]
 33,6 us/s;;;;;Interrupt;[132] iwlwifi
 27,3 us/s;;;;;Interrupt;[3] net_rx(softirq)
 18,0 us/s;;;;;Process;[kworker/2:2]
 16,4 us/s;;;;;Timer;watchdog_timer_fn
 15,6 us/s;;;;;kWork;vmstat_update
 14,3 us/s;;;;;Process;[kworker/0:1]
 13,6 us/s;;;;;Interrupt;[127] ahci[0000:00:17.0]
 13,5 us/s;;;;;Timer;clocksource_watchdog
  8,9 us/s;;;;;Process;[kworker/3:1]
  8,0 us/s;;;;;kWork;i915_gem_retire_work_handler
  7,8 us/s;;;;;Process;[kworker/7:1]
  6,7 us/s;;;;;Process;[kworker/1:2]
  5,7 us/s;;;;;Process;[kworker/3:1H]
  5,6 us/s;;;;;Process;[kworker/4:1]
  5,5 us/s;;;;;Process;[kworker/6:1]
  4,8 us/s;;;;;Process;[kworker/u17:0]
  1,3 us/s;;;;;Process;[kworker/5:2]
  1,1 us/s;;;;;Timer;blk_rq_timed_out_timer
  0,9 us/s;;;;;Process;nm-applet
  0,8 us/s;;;;;Process;[kworker/1:1H]
  0,8 us/s;;;;;Timer;timerfd_tmrproc
  0,7 us/s;;;;;Timer;commit_timeout
  0,5 us/s;;;;;Process;[ksoftirqd/3]
;;;;;;

____________________________________________________________________
 *  *  *   Device Power Report   *  *  *

Usage;Device Name
  3,1%;DRAM
  3,1%;CPU misc
100,0%;Codec audio hwC0D0 : Realtek
  3,1%;CPU core
  0,9 ops/s;GPU core
  0,9 ops/s;GPU misc
 26,9%;Display backlight
100,0%;Périphérique radio : iwlwifi
100,0%;Périphérique USB : usb-device-8087-0a2a
100,0%;Périphérique radio : btusb
100,0%;Périphérique USB : xHCI Host Controller
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Intel Corporation Wireless 7265
  0,0%;Périphérique USB : BisonCam, NB Pro (Generic)
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
  0,0 pkts/s;Interface réseau :  wlp4s0 (iwlwifi)
  0,0 pkts/s;Interface réseau :  enp3s0f1 (r8169)
  0,0%;Codec audio hwC0D2 : Intel
  0,0%;Périphérique USB : xHCI Host Controller
  0,0%;runtime-simple-framebuffer.0
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
  0,0%;runtime-efivars.0
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16)
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M]
  0,0%;runtime-PNP0103:00
  0,0%;runtime-rtsx_pci_ms.0
  0,0%;runtime-PNP0C09:00
  0,0%;runtime-INT33A1:00
  0,0%;runtime-PNP0C0D:00
  0,0%;runtime-PNP0C14:00
  0,0%;runtime-rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0
  0,0%;runtime-coretemp.0
  0,0%;runtime-alarmtimer
  0,0%;runtime-microcode
  0,0%;runtime-MSFT0101:00
  0,0%;runtime-INT0800:00
  0,0%;runtime-regulatory.0
  0,0%;runtime-PNP0C0E:00
  0,0%;runtime-PNP0C04:00
  0,0%;I2C Adapter (i2c-0): i915 gmbus dpc
  0,0%;Périphérique PCI :  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus
  0,0%;runtime-PNP0C0A:00
  0,0%;runtime-ACPI0003:00
  0,0%;runtime-pcspkr
  0,0%;runtime-PNP0C0C:00
  0,0%;runtime-serial8250
  0,0%;runtime-PNP0C14:01
  0,0%;runtime-i8042
  0,0%;runtime-ACPI000C:00
  0,0%;I2C Adapter (i2c-3): DPDDC-A
  0,0%;I2C Adapter (i2c-1): i915 gmbus dpb
  0,0%;I2C Adapter (i2c-4): DPDDC-B
  0,0%;I2C Adapter (i2c-2): i915 gmbus dpd
____________________________________________________________________
 *  *  *   Process Device Activity   *  *  *

Process;Device
systemd;/dev/autofs
;/dev/kmsg
;/dev/rfkill
systemd-journal;/dev/kmsg
;/dev/kmsg
systemd-logind;/dev/input/event1
;/dev/input/event2
;/dev/input/event3
;/dev/input/event4
;/dev/input/event5
;/dev/input/event6
bluetoothd;/dev/rfkill
acpid;/dev/input/event0
;/dev/input/event1
;/dev/input/event10
;/dev/input/event11
;/dev/input/event12
;/dev/input/event13
;/dev/input/event14
;/dev/input/event15
;/dev/input/event2
;/dev/input/event3
;/dev/input/event4
;/dev/input/event5
;/dev/input/event6
wpa_supplicant;/dev/rfkill
;/dev/rfkill
Xorg;/dev/dri/card1
;/dev/input/event0
;/dev/input/event1
;/dev/input/event2
;/dev/input/event4
;/dev/input/event5
;/dev/input/event6
;/dev/input/event7
;/dev/input/event8
;/dev/vga_arbiter
upowerd;/dev/input/event3
gvfsd-fuse;/dev/fuse
indicator-bluet;/dev/rfkill
pulseaudio;/dev/snd/controlC0
;/dev/snd/controlC0
;/dev/snd/controlC0
compiz;/dev/dri/card1
fwupd;/dev/bus/usb/001/002

____________________________________________________________________
 *  *  *   AHCI ALPM Residency Statistics - Not supported on this macine   *  *  *

____________________________________________________________________
 *  *  *   Software Settings in Need of Tuning   *  *  *

Description;Script
VM writeback timeout;echo '1500' > '/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs';
NMI watchdog devrait être désactivé;echo '0' > '/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog';
Permettre la gestion d'énergie du codec Audio;echo '1' > '/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save';
Enable SATA link power management for host1;echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy';
Enable SATA link power management for host2;echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host2/link_power_management_policy';
Enable SATA link power management for host3;echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host3/link_power_management_policy';
Enable SATA link power management for host0;echo 'min_power' > '/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy';
Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-0 (i915 gmbus dpc);echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-0/device/power/control';
Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-2 (i915 gmbus dpd);echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-2/device/power/control';
Auto-suspension de périphérique USB inconnu 1-8 (8087:0a2a);echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8/power/control';
Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-1 (i915 gmbus dpb);echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/device/power/control';
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio;echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/power/control';
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers;echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/power/control';
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller;echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.1/power/control';
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics;echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/power/control';
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Intel Corporation Wireless 7265;echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:04:00.0/power/control';
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller;echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.0/power/control';
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus;echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.4/power/control';
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC;echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/power/control';
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287;echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/power/control';
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem;echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.2/power/control';
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller;echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.0/power/control';
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1;echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/power/control';
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M];echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control';
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode];echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:17.0/power/control';
État du Wake-on-lan pour le périphérique enp3s0f1;ethtool -s enp3s0f1 wol d;
____________________________________________________________________
 *  *  *   Untunable Software Issues   *  *  *

Description
I2C Adapter i2c-3 has no runtime power management
I2C Adapter i2c-4 has no runtime power management
____________________________________________________________________
 *  *  *   Optimal Tuned Software Settings   *  *  *

Description
État de l'interface du périphérique bluetooth
Auto-suspension du périphérique USB xHCI Host Controller [usb1]
Auto-suspension du périphérique USB BisonCam, NB Pro [Generic]
Auto-suspension du périphérique USB xHCI Host Controller [usb2]
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16)
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1
Runtime PM pour périphérique PCI  Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5
État du Wake-on-lan pour le périphérique wlp4s0
```

Comment: I've had no trouble with my System76 skylake, but see [this post](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/41713.html) on the issue.

Comment: I see you are using Kernel 4.8 release candidate 7. In my bug mail this morning a user on rc8 says all cstate problems have gone away for him.

Comment: Also, someone reported a firmware issue on Skylake Dells that would do exactly what you described... and he also posted the workaround: update to the latest firmware *and* force it to reset all UEFI settings after that (it will change some invisible settings too, which would get in the way of the workaround otherwise). This should allow a system otherwise limited to PC3 to be able to reach PC8.

Answer (score 3):

First, update the motherboard firmware to the latest, and keep it up-to-date.

Second, please install the intel-microcode package (and you must use version 3.20160714.1 or later, so get it from Ubuntu YY or from Debian).

Ensure you have microcode 0x9d or 0x9e after you reboot (in /proc/cpuinfo or in the kernel log).

This will help some (it will at least get some potentially crashing behavior out of the way), but it will not solve everything. The NVMe issue with PC3 remains, and that requires code that is not yet in the Linux kernel, and possibly some information Intel did not tell anyone about yet.

Comment: Would the newer microcode have pstate improvements to improve Turbo boost and thermal issues on my Ivy Bridge 3630QM?

Comment: It depends on what version of the Ivy Bridge microcode you are already running, but basically, if you already have any recent version of intel-microcode installed, no, it won't help.  Laptop heat sinks are very often partially broken and the owner just notices it as a tendency to overheat faster, so you might want to replace the thermal compound on yours and re-seat it (but you will need to use one of those very expensive ones for top overclockers.  I hear in the ThinkPad forums that Arctic Silver 5 is a good choice).

Comment: Also, apparently someone has been spreading misinformation about how to mess with the Turbo Boost on Ivy Bridge, and if you follow it, it disables everything.  Basically, you have to set the BIOS to performance mode, *enable* the CPU power saving C-states, EIST, Turbo boost, etc. *and* ensure you actually have thermal room *and power room, which is a lot more difficult to know* for Turbo boost to engage.

Comment: I noticed the heat was 10 degrees hotter upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04  to 16.04 which meant kernel 3.13 to 4.4. Conky then showed CPUs increased from 2400 MHz to 3400 MHz launching apps. My microcode is set to Ubuntu 16.04 intel additional drivers. I have bad luck doing things like ripping off heat sinks and glueing them back on. Echoing '1' to no-turbo flag reduces heat (but makes nifty turbo boost go away :( )

Comment: Hmm, can you prepare a live-cd on USB, ensure it works, *disable* all internal M2/NVMe/SATA ports, and use the USB live-cd?  If that fixes it, it is a firmware issue with your SATA/M2 ports that are limiting the system to PC3.  For Dells, fix it by using the UEFI command to reset all settings (yes, even if you never touched them in the first place) *AFTER* you update to the latest firmware.   For non-Dell, report the bug to the vendor, explain that Dell had the same issue and it required a fix to the firmware, and request help.

Comment: You pegged it right--Dell Inspiron 17R 7220 SE. Under kernel 4.4 and 4.6.3 (ad says Dell laptop fixes) when USB hub plugged in weird boot stuff happened plus HDMI TV had to be turned on first or off first depending on unknown reasons. I've never used EFI. Your advice is uncanny!

Comment: I forgot to mention USB issue totally disappeared under Kernel 4.7.3

Answer (score 0):

As you have a laptop with NVIDIA graphics card (probably in "Optimus" configuration), it may share a heat sink with your processor and integrated graphics.

In that case, it may help to install the Nvidia proprietary drivers:

- `sudo apt install nvidia-375`

That helped to fix overheating issues in my case. I guess an alternative would be to use the nouveau driver somehow and or otherwise make sure the nvidia card's fans activated.