# Intel SkyLake Blank Screen on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics

When I recently installed Ubuntu 16.10 on a new machine (ASRock Z170 Gaming-ITX/AC S1151 M-ITX Intel Motherboard with Intel Core Skylake Processor i5-6500/3.2 GHz Processor CPU), I got a blank screen on first boot.

After a lot of searching around on the web, I discovered I could boot correctly into Linux using `nomodeset` on the kernel command line.  However, this limits my graphics options as `xrandr -q` only reports one monitor:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

I've read lots of websites suggesting that this was a problem in earlier kernel versions (which need `i915.preliminary_hw_support=1`) and that with 4.3+ it should be fine, but I have:

`Linux mypc 4.8.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 18 14:39:52 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

So I think this shouldn't be a problem.  Based on some websites I've read, I've tried all of the following kernel options (and a few combinations largely at random), but none have helped:

```
i915.preliminary_hw_support=1
i915.i915_enable_rc6=1
nolapic
```

In all cases, I removed `quiet splash` so that I could see what was happening.  Depending on the option, the visible boot process gets to a different place.  With `nomodeset` it gets all the way to the virtual console (I started with a server install so I could better choose the packages I wanted).  Without `nomodeset`, it gets as far as:

```
[    5.088899] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from VESA VGA
```

With `nolapic` as the only addition, it gets a couple of lines further on (both related to SATA stuff I think).  This might be relatively random though as I've tried this a few times and got to a different stage in the SATA stuff (but always within a 100th of a second or so after the `fb:` line)

With `i915.i915_enable_rc6=1`, I get a message saying:

```
i915: unknown parameter 'i915_enable_rc6' ignored`
```

So that's obviously not doing anything.

I've also tried adding `i915` and `nvme` into `/etc/modules`, but again: no discernible effect.

All of the above came from various different forums (and this site), but I'm afraid I didn't keep note of all of the references - hence not linking to any of the original questions.

In the case of the empty kernel line (just the stuff added by the installer and no `nomodeset`), if I ssh into the machine and `startx`, I can run `xrandr` and see:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   1280x1024     60.02 +  75.02
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94
   1152x864      75.00
   1280x720      60.00    59.94
   1024x768      75.03    72.00    70.07    60.00
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  50.00    59.94    59.99
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94
   1600x1200     60.00
   1680x1050     59.88
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02
   1440x900      59.90
   1280x960      60.00
   1366x768      59.79
   1152x864      75.00
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
   832x624       74.55
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94
   720x400       70.08
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1280x1024 (0x4a) 540.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock 319.91KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock 300.10Hz
```

... suggesting the driver is working to some degree, there's just nothing being drawn on the screen.

Can anyone offer any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong?

I can obviously add more information as required, but I'm not sure what to add at the moment.

---

**Edit 1**

This is my current grub configuration /etc/default/grub

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

This is the bit of /boot/grub/grub.cfg that seems most relevant:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-c21835f3-4aaf-4880-b573-19a361a72db9' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  c21835f3-4aaf-4880-b573-19a361a72db9
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c21835f3-4aaf-4880-b573-19a361a72db9
        fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-26-generic root=UUID=c21835f3-4aaf-4880-b573-19a361a72db9 ro  nomodeset
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-26-generic
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

The Xorg.log is here: http://pastebin.com/nvNwTPj4

I've rebooted and (in the grub edit screen) removed nomodeset and also removed the gfxmode line (since I've had some comments about removing vga=, but haven't actually got vga= to remove).  This resulted in the same blank screen as before.

I've also tried just having `text` on the boot line, but this got to the same place as without anything (`switching to inteldrmfb` etc as above).

---

**Edit 3**

Following a suggestion from @Mladen:

- I've now tried installing the intel graphics drivers from https://01.org/linuxgraphics/intel-linux-graphics-firmwares - both Skylake ones - the GuC and DMC installed according to the instructions.  I then rebooted without `nomodeset` on the boot line and the screen went blank at the same point as in the other tests.  Interestingly though, it stated:

  W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
  W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915

The output of `ls -l /lib/firmware/i915` shows:

```
total 412
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8380 Aug 15 15:40 bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 Aug 15 15:40 bxt_dmc_ver1.bin -> bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8616 Aug 15 15:40 kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 Aug 15 15:40 kbl_dmc_ver1.bin -> kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8824 Sep 14 13:47 skl_dmc_ver1_23.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8928 Nov 10 17:54 skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     38 Nov 10 17:54 skl_dmc_ver1.bin -> /lib/firmware/i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 109636 Aug 15 15:40 skl_guc_ver1.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 128320 Aug 15 15:40 skl_guc_ver4.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 129024 Nov 10 17:53 skl_guc_ver6_1.bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     37 Nov 10 17:53 skl_guc_ver6.bin -> /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver6_1.bin
```

which shows much earlier versions of firmware than the ones that initramfs seems to be expecting

- Following this, I followed the instructions [here](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2016/11/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-8-6-in-linux.html) to upgrade to kernel version 4.8.6 (this also reported the missing firmware lines as above).  I then rebooted (again without `nomodeset`) and again it got to exactly the same place.
- Since the error above had seemed to relate to firmware for Kabylake and Broxton processors (although I'm fairly sure I have a Skylake one), I downloaded the latest files for those two from [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/intel-linux-graphics-firmwares) - this only seems to be DMC stuff though.  Installing both of those produced the same messages regarding missing firmware (presumably since they were DMC files and the version numbers were different).  Unsurprisingly, the result is exactly the same: without `nomodeset`, the screen freezes after `fb: switching to inteldrmfb from VESA VGA`.

From what I've read, these firmware files are related to unreleased processors, so it's unlikely to be relevant anyway, but I thought it was worth a try.

---

**Edit 4**

In case it helps, I've pasted a complete `dmesg` output from a [nomodeset boot](http://pastebin.com/gL5bvSXp) and a [non-nomodeset, blank screen boot](http://pastebin.com/HA8SNQJa).  There are some differences (including loading of the `skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin` file, but I'm not sure what to make of it all...

---

**Edit 5**

I've also now tried this with kernel 4.8.7, but the behaviour is the same as with 4.8.0 or 4.8.6. Installing the intel microcode version 3.20160714.1 also didn't make any noticeable difference.

---

**Edit 6**

In case this turns out to be a kernel bug related in some way to [this one](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=86551), I've raised a bug on the kernel bugzilla page - https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=187601

Comment: Sorry for not commenting, but I am lacking reputation... Anyways; Maybe [this](https://wiki.debian.org/KernelModesetting) helps? >If you launch your kernel with a vga=xxx option on the boot line, it will fail (black screen). Yes, I know it says linux-2.6 there, but maybe removing said option is worth a try? Let me know if that did anything... ###EDIT
Apparently removing the vga=xxx option has helped someone with a similar problem [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/screen-goes-black-on-startup-892419/)

Comment: @rocket_doge_ Thanks, but I don't have a vga=xxx option at the moment - I've added details of the grub configuration above.  There is a graphics mode thing (`GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768`) - do you think this could be relevant?  I can't remember what the setting was when I originally installed Ubuntu (but it obviously didn't work!)

Comment: what does your /var/log/Xorg.0.log say ?

Comment: @Amias: http://pastebin.com/nvNwTPj4

Comment: i had similar issues and found that a xanmod 4.7 kernel vastly improved the stability of the intel graphics and optimus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the display port ? I am also having troubles with skylake, kernel 4.8 and i915 drivers with Ubuntu 16.10 ==> Intel didn't release the latest graphics stack for 16.10 yet.

You could try to:

1) Switch back to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (and kernel 4.4.x)

2) Use kernel 4.6.7: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6.7/

3) Use the latest drm-intel-nightly kernel: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/drm-intel-nightly/
(but there is no amd64 successful build available anymore, last was 2016-10-19)

Comment: For reference I am using the drm-intel-nightly kernel version 4.9.0-994 amd64 built 2016-10-19. I had trouble with my thinkpad t460s display port.

Comment: Thank you @MisterZ.  I'm not using the display port: I have two monitors - one with HDMI, DVI and VGA ports: this is connected via HDMI; and one with VGA only - this is now connected via an HDMI-VGA adaptor but in early testing wasn't connected at all.

Comment: I've tried Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - it was after I had the same problem described above that I decided to try 16.10 in the hope the problem was fixed.  Is there any reason why you think kernel 4.6.7 will work while Ubuntu 16.04 and kernels 4.8.* don't?

Comment: They don't pack the same version of intel display drivers. The kernel 4.7.x or 4.8.x didn't solve my problems. So I tried out the latest 4.6.x and drm-intel-nightly and it both worked out for me.

Comment: Okay, thanks @MisterZ. Do you know where I can get the 2016-10-19 build? It's not available at the link you provided. Don't worry if not: I'll keep an eye on that link and will try the next working amd64 build.

Comment: I've tested 4.6.7 and the results are the same as with Ubuntu 16.04, 16.10 and kernels 4.8.*.

Comment: Quick & dirty drm-intel-nightly kernel 4.9.0-994 amd64 upload: http://dl.free.fr/wos3ldfCE

Comment: We have a winner! It looks like your compiled version of 4.9.0 works. Will do some more testing, but many many thanks!

Comment: Latest amd64 build succeeded again: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/drm-intel-nightly/2016-11-18/

Answer (score 2):

### Bug Report

Your error:

```
[    5.088899] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from VESA VGA
```

Is similar to this one discussed in 2014 bug report: ([Screen freezes on boot at "fb: switching to inteldrmfb from simple"](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=86551)). However it was supposed to have been been fixed in Kernel 3.17 / 3.18.

### Kernel Version 4.8.7

Kernel Version 4.8.7 has many patches for Intel i915 driver (and Radeon which many in AU might be interested in) as discussed here: ([Softpedia News - Linux kernel 4-8-7 updates intel and radeon drivers improves wireless support](http://news.softpedia.com/news/linux-kernel-4-8-7-updates-intel-and-radeon-drivers-improves-wireless-support-510122.shtml)). Indeed some wireless users might want this kernel update too.

The story provides a link for downloading the kernel but do not use it. Rather go to ([kernel.ubuntu.com ~kernel v4.8.7](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.7/)). If someone needs step by step instructions please comment and I'll add them here.

### Known i915 freezes

The i915 DRM driver is known to cause various GPU hangs, crashes and even full system freezes. It might be necessary to disable hardware acceleration to workaround these issues.

One solution you haven't tried is to use the following Xorg configuration by editing (or creating) the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with these lines:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "DRI"   "false"
EndSection
```

Save and reboot (without the nomodeset).

If the black screen problems go away but Google-Chrome or Fire Fox freezes you will have to disable hardware acceleration in them.

### Most recent Intel firmware

Another important consideration is your Intel firmware which is discussed in this AU article ([Ubuntu 16.04 Skylake overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830404/ubuntu-16-04-skylake-overheating)) and it should be at version 3.20160714.1 or later as of Septeber 27, 2016.

Comment: Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix, but alas still no joy. You certainly had my hopes up with all the i915 fixes in 4.8.7. With 4.8.7, the behaviour is the same as with 4.8.0 or 4.8.6. Installing that version of the intel microcode didn't make any noticeable difference. I haven't tried the Xorg fix as it isn't really viable: it's a server and doesn't start X until I log in and then type `startx`, which is rather awkward when the screen has locked up. Mostly I just use the machine in the virtual terminal, so if that doesn't work, it's a bit of a non-starter.

Comment: @DrAl I'm sorry to hear the road-blocks are still there. I'll keep this post in mind and come back if I discover anything new (or remember anything old).

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same motherboard and had display issues when first trying to setup linux - not sure if it is a mix of faulty driver and faulty motherboard firmware or just faulty driver but i found the following:

With 2 x HDMI monitors plugged in - shows post screen and initial boot but no GUI

With 1 x HDMI in port above Display Port connector (HDMI1 in M/B user manual)  - no GUI

With 1 x HDMI in port to left of Display Port connector (HDMI2 in m/b user manual) - works fine, GUI displays okay

With 1 x Display Port & 1 x HDMI2 connected displays - works fine, GUI on both screens.

With 1 x Display Port & 1 x HDMI1 connected displays - works partially, GUI on DP screen, HDMI1 screen blank though shows as connected in xrandr output.

All above is on fully updated Ubuntu 16.04 with no kernel parameters needed (i did need the i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 setting initially due to the kernel version at the time but this is no longer needed)

I've not been able to get three displays working under Linux - though they do work okay under Windows 10.

Note: I also recently updated the M/B to latest firmware which resolved a problem with ACPI error messages filling up dmesg making it useless for diagnostic purposes so also worth doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help, but I remember having similar problems when trying to install ubuntu on my Asus with an intel skylake. I don't know where the problem exactly might be, but this helped me out.

- Remove the "quiet splash" from the kernel line and add "nomodeset" as you've done before. This will give you more information which might be useful, and you might be able to access the system for the following two steps.
- Other option: remove "quiet splash" but insert "text" to boot to text mode
- If that works, try updating to the newest linux kernel (should be 4.8.6 as I'm writing.) You can find a guide [here](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2016/11/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-8-6-in-linux.html).
- I also suggest installing the intel graphical drivers/firmware from [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/intel-linux-graphics-firmwares).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Mladen.  The first point (no "quiet splash" and adding "nomodeset") is exactly what I have been doing to get into the system.

Comment: Sorry - submitted that comment before I meant to... I tried the intel graphics drivers (unsuccessfully) when I initially installed 16.04; I can't remember which kernel this was with, so I'll try that again on 16.10 in case it makes a difference.  I'll have a go with 4.8.6 and will report back; given that this issue was allegedly fixed in 4.3, it seems optimistic.  I've struggled to find any release notes that would show the differences between 4.8 and 4.8.6 to see whether there are any relevant fixes - do you know where I might find them?

Comment: @DrAl Don't take my word as expertise, since everything I write is "selftaught" trough the internet, so what I'm writing might as well be wrong - but here we go.
I think the issue might have been solved for other (older) cpus, but I know I had issues with the skylake even with the "fixed issues" note on the linux kernels, at least for those that ubuntu is using. When I first installed ubuntu and it finally ran, some firmware stuff was out of control. For example the fans went off at full speed after ~2min after the boot, some functional keys (light, airplane mode) still don't work properly.

Comment: @DrAl What solved most critical problems for me was installing proprietary drivers (intel, nvidia) and installing the latest linux kernel.

Comment: @DrAl Unfortunately I wasn't able to find release changelogs either, but some softpedia articles on each release updates...
4.8.1: http://news.softpedia.com/news/linux-kernel-4-8-1-is-out-stable-enough-for-deployment-in-gnu-linux-distros-509070.shtml
4.8.2: http://news.softpedia.com/news/linux-kernel-4-8-2-is-out-with-x86-and-arm-improvements-updated-drivers-509334.shtml <- might be of importance to you
4.8.4: http://news.softpedia.com/news/linux-kernel-4-8-4-released-with-ext4-and-btrfs-improvements-updated-drivers-509542.shtml

Comment: @DrAl 4.8.5: http://news.softpedia.com/news/linux-kernel-4-8-5-lands-with-numerous-cifs-arm64-and-powerpc-improvements-509769.shtml
4.8.6 : http://news.softpedia.com/news/linux-kernel-4-8-6-updates-wireless-and-amdgpu-drivers-fixes-arm-issues-509850.shtml <- might also contain updates that interest you.

Comment: @DrAl Also updated the answer, wrote some wrong stuff. You might wanna try the text mode when booting.

Comment: thanks for that.  I've tried removing `nomodeset` and just having `text`, but it still locks up when it gets to `fb: switching to inteldrmfb from VESA VGA`.  I'll revisit the intel graphics drivers and then try the kernel upgrade tomorrow as I don't have time this evening unfortunately.

Comment: I've now tried everything in your suggestion list (thanks again) and, as you'll see in Edit 3 above, nothing is working at present.  I don't suppose you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Hm, not really. I can think of two things I would try, but at this point, it's just guessing and hoping to walk into the bug by sheer luck. So maybe try this: 1) Boot with nomodeset and then get all ubuntu updates (sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade) 2) try to see if you actually use the correct drivers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system

Comment: Here are my outputs for:
1) `sudo lshw -c` video http://pastebin.com/TrtMAW4h
2) `modinfo i915` http://pastebin.com/QyWbjMxF
I know we have different systems, but maybe you can find something.