# I still get blackscreen even after nomodeset

Tags: boot, dell, nomodeset

I got the screen like this when i start my computer

[image]

Even when i add “nomodeset”, i get the same black screen as below Black screen even after nomodeset

[image]

I tried to open terminal using ctrl+alt+F1....F11, nothing works! Please help!

> OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bit)
>
> Graphics : llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)
>
> Machine : Dell

Comment: Please give detail OS version, machine, detail of graphics in your system and operation you executed before ths problem occur.

Comment: @Ajay I've updated the details

Comment: try disable Secure Boot in BIOS  and if it not work edit and post output of lspci | grep VGA

Comment: @Ajay It does not work after disabling secure boot. Below is the output

**00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)**

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this is the reason as discussed in [No version of Ubuntu can be installed with any Skylake 6th generation Intel processor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691216/no-version-of-ubuntu-can-be-installed-with-any-skylake-6th-generation-intel-proc) post.

Here is the solution as suggested by [Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/users/167850/pilot6)

Boot with `nomodeset` boot parameter as it is described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/167850).

You will be able to install Ubuntu. After you do it, the system will probably won't boot again.

You will have to get to grub menu by pressing Shift or ESC button and enter `nomodeset` again.

Then  install 4.3 kernel. It can be done this way. Run in terminal:

```
mkdir ~/linux-4.3
cd ~/linux-4.3
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3-wily/linux-headers-4.3.0-040300-generic_4.3.0-040300.201511020949_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3-wily/linux-headers-4.3.0-040300_4.3.0-040300.201511020949_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3-wily/linux-image-4.3.0-040300-generic_4.3.0-040300.201511020949_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

and reboot. I hope the system will boot without the `nomodeset` parameter.

**Notice:** The kernel will not get updates. You will need to install them manually from [Mainline kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).